# problem with php rename function (remaning file, which file name has space)

Tags: php, codeigniter

After file upload, I am renaming with this code (in CI)

```
rename ( "./upload/temp/{$data1['upload_data']['client_name']}", "./upload/$filename" );
```

but there are any space in file name it's gives this massage, like for file name "New Text Document (2).txt" the massage is

```
Message: rename(./upload/temp/New Text Document (2).txt,./upload/4.txt) [function.rename]: No error
```

How I can fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should probably replace all spaces with `\` (backslash + space), for example:

```
$toRename = str_replace(
                array(' ', '(', ')'),  
                array('\ ', '\(', '\)'),  
                $data1['upload_data']['client_name']
);

rename(
    './upload/temp/' . $toRename,
    './upload/' . $filename
);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but now with your solution i am getting this problem Message: rename(./upload/temp/New\ Text\ Document\ (2).txt,./upload/7.txt) [function.rename]: No error

Comment: `(` and `)` could be problematic as well, please try updated code.

Comment: with new code this one is coming Message: rename(./upload/temp/New\ Text\ Document\ \(2\).txt,./upload/8.txt) [function.rename]: No error

Comment: i think any how we need to remove the spaces

Comment: It seems (2) is not escaped in your case, can you please double check it?

Comment: Thanks David Kuridža for your Help